# How to keep a file object in python open and keep writing to it without having to call file.close()

Tags: python, file

This is a really basic question but I want to know if its possible to open a file and keep writing to it while the actual file gets update in real time.

Basically I want to be able to do this and have 'File' act kinda like sys.stdout where you don't have to close the file for the output to be visible.

```
File = open("File.txt", "w")
File.write("Hello")
```

Comment: You don't have to close the file. You can keep the file handle around and keep writing to it until you're done with it. Are you planning to read the file from another program while you are writing to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is use the flush function:

```
File = open("File.txt", "w")
File.write("Hello")
File.flush()
```

This will have the output written to the file without closing the connection.